# Import Array from file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, file, import

I have an array of strings in their own file that I'm looking to use as a variable in my client side Javascript. I've been trying various `$.getJSON` and `function loadJSON(callback){}` solutions but everything is giving me the error `GET http://localhost:3001/strings.json 404 (Not Found)`

(I've also tried it with the file called `strings.js` and get the same results)

both the `strings.json` file and my client side JavaScript file are in the `/public/js/` directory, so I'm fairly certain it isn't a path issue.

script.js

```
$.getJSON("strings.json", function(json){
    console.log(json);
});
```

strings.json

```
["string 1","string 2","string 3", "string 4", "etc"]
```

Edit: Added the small amount of actually relevant code. I'm aware `strings.json` is not actually json, but it seemed like the most logical file type. Please let me know if there's something better.

Comment: please share the entire code

Comment: What happens when you point the browser at `http://localhost:3001/strings.json`?

Comment: _"both the strings.json file and my client side JavaScript file are in the `/public/js/` directory"_ , _"`GET http://localhost:3001/strings.json 404 (Not Found)`"_ You are not requesting the resource from `/public/js/` directory. Change URL passed to `$.getJSON()` to `"http://localhost:3001/public/js/strings.json"`

Comment: @Malvolio I included in the question, I get a 404 not found error. More specifically, the page renders: Cannot GET /strings.json

Comment: @guest271314 I didn't think I needed to request the specific path because the files were in the same directory, but I tried that anyway and am still getting the same error. edit: that does work

Comment: @Rokitar Only you can determine which directory the file is located within. You can use the full path to the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying it as is, *your file couldn't be found*.

The path you provided for your `$.getJSON` is incorrect, unless you place `strings.json` in the same directory of your webpage.

Try placing an absolute path in the function, IE:

```
$.getJSON("/public/js/strings.json", function(json){
    console.log(json);
});
```

EDIT: If it is in the same directory already, try lead the path with a "./" to indicate the path is in the same directory:

```
$.getJSON("./strings.json", function(json){
    console.log(json);
});
```

EDIT: Lastly, if you still can't navigate properly, you can also try to submit a path as a parameter to `$.getJSON` coming from your server script. If you use ASP C#, for example you can use:

```
currPath = Page.ResolveUrl("~/public/js/strings.json");
```

Then pass `currPath` as a parameter for `pathVal` below:

```
    function getThis(pathVal){
        $.getJSON(pathVal, function(json){
             console.log(json);
         });
      }
```

Or something equivalent in php. Note that it might make your code messy though, but it works.